# Rails, rake does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ubuntu-10.04

I've been trying to use Rails and when I use rake, I get this error. Any suggestions on which run time should I use?

```
ngzhongqin@ngzhongqin-linux:~/RailsProjects/webuiltit$ rake db:create:all --trace
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/execjs-1.2.4/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:45:in `autodetect'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/execjs-1.2.4/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/execjs-1.2.4/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.0/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.0/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/RailsProjects/webuiltit/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/ngzhongqin/RailsProjects/webuiltit/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/ngzhongqin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you still doing 'rake db:create:all' ?  have you tried 'rake db:create ' ?  Also, do you get the same error trying to run the server (script/rails server for rails3, script/server for rails2)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have installed the gem therubyracer, execjs, mustang but nothing worked.

On my linux (ubuntu) the command

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

did the job finally for me.

May be this post could also be helpful: https://github.com/intridea/rails_wizard/issues/31

Comment: Yes! This was the one. Ubuntu Rails321 ruby192

Comment: Note, to get `execjs` to "detect" the installed gem for `therubyracer`, you *must* add the following line to your `Gemfile`: `gem 'therubyracer', require: "v8"`. Apparently Bundler hides access to gems that are not specified there (in the `Gemfile`). Installing `nodejs` via `apt-get` will of course work as well (but that package isn't available on all Linux systems, like the current stable version of Debian).

Answer (score 31):

Add this to your Gemfile

`gem 'therubyracer', require: "v8"`

and run

`bundle install`

Comment: I do this after install the `therubyracer` gem, and, finally, it works. Thanks very much.

Comment: I had to uncomment this line from my GemFile

Comment: It's worth noting, apparently installing `therubyracer` gem alone *does not do the trick*... One would think `execjs` would "automatically pick the best runtime available" ([as it claims to](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs)), but for some reason *you must* add the relevant line to your `Gemfile`. (Perhaps this is a 'feature' of Bundler, whereby it's hiding gems not in `Gemfile`?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install runtime for these.. some of the good options are

`therubyracer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby`

`therubyrhino - Mozilla Rhino embedded within JRuby`

`Johnson - Mozilla SpiderMonkey embedded within Ruby`

`Mustang - Mustang V8 embedded within Ruby`

`Node.js`

`Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X`

`Mozilla SpiderMonkey`

`Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript)`

you can find more details at https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

Comment: -1, No command or direct solution provided whatsoever, just general info which is only confusing me as a rails beginner.

Comment: @tarrasch why should the poster provide a command for you to blindly paste into your shell? The series of steps depends on the distribution installed and which package you want to install to meet the requirement.

Comment: @AdamHawes, I agree with you, but I think *this* answer not only have no "line to blindly paste", it just doesn't provide any explanation in text to compensate for that, it's just a listing of stuff I've never heard of before.

Comment: @Tarrasch so Google for some of those things! Each of them solves the problem. The execjs page tells you what they're for already. All you need to do is install one, and that's different depending on what OS/distro you use!