# rake db:create - Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Here is the error I get:

```
sergio@sergio-VirtualBox:~/blog$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

sergio@sergio-VirtualBox:~/blog$
```

So after some searching it seems I need to install a Javascript runtime for Ruby.

Is there a difference between the many different options? It seems Node.js is the easiest to install, will this come back to bite me or is this choice OK?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376021/rails-rake-does-not-work), seems to be what I'm looking for but I don't know how to make use of it. Where do I find this "gemfile" and is it a per rails project file or a global ruby file? I'm very confused and can't seem to get my bearings and multiple answers contradict each other and don't solve the issue.

> Add this to your Gemfile
>
> gem 'therubyracer', require: "v8"
>
> and run
>
> bundle install

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Ruby itself doesn't require a JS runtime, but a default new Rails application does.

There's a file called `Gemfile` in your main application directory (i.e. per Rails project) which is a list of gems required for your project that you can install using `bundle install`.

Adding the line `gem 'therubyracer'` and then `bundle install` will install the ruby racer JS runtime, which I've found to be the simplest if you're on a 64bit OS.

You can find more information about your `Gemfile` at the [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) site.

Comment: More detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime

Answer (score 6):

Have you installed Node.js on your computer yet? It needs to be installed on your computer as well.

here is the link to download, http://nodejs.org/#download

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Why would rake need Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

There are several fairly similar options such rubytheracer, node and execjs.

rubytheracer has fallen out of favor due to its code size.  Vendors such as Heroku (for rails) actively discourage it.

I currently recommend node.js

More info at [Rails - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: Fallen out of favor *due to its code size?* In the Rails crowd?! Surely you jest, sir.

Answer (score 0):

insert gem 'therubyracer'  in Gemfile in a new line
1. run

gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.4'

1. run

bundle install

This will work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but then I reinstalled Ruby193 with all the checkboxes (Tc/Tk, associate rb, and add to PATH).

And then deleted the `GEMFile.lock`

Edited the Gemfile whereever I saw gem therubyracer, I changed it to: gem therubyracer, :platform => :ruby

- Then `bundle install`
- Then `rake db:drop`
- Then `rake db:create`
- Then `rake db:migrate`

and so on

Answer (score -1):

Just `gem install "therubyracer"` and it just works.