# Runnig Rake tasks on production server failes due to ExecJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I have a Rails 4 application installed on RHEL 6 machine.

The production uses Passenger and Apache2.

Lately I've been trying to integrate Rake tasks into production as a scheduled job using Whenever Gem and Cron.

Whenever I try to run in production one of these Rake tasks, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
```

It is important to mention the NodeJS was installed on the machine. I can precompile assets, and so on.
Specifically, the command    `node --version` produces:     `v0.10.31`

Here's my stack trace:

```
  rake aborted!
    ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect'
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    /var/www/eng_performance/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.5.3/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    /var/www/eng_performance/releases/20141014084554/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/www/eng_performance/releases/20141014084554/Rakefile:4:in `require'
    /var/www/eng_performance/releases/20141014084554/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Note:** 
I've installed NodeJS as a compilation from source, because when I tried to install from the repo I got this error that I didn't know how to overcome:

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    c-ares19-1.9.1-5.el6.3.x86_64 from epel
    http-parser-2.0-4.20121128gitcd01361.el6.x86_64 from epel
    1:libuv-0.10.28-1.el6.x86_64 from epel
    nodejs-0.10.30-1.el6.x86_64 from epel
    1:v8-3.14.5.10-11.el6.x86_64 from epel
```

Comment: Could you check if `gem 'therubyracer'` is uncommented in your Gemfile?

Comment: @RMilushev, thanks for the reply.
As far as I understand, using therubyracer isn't recommended as to performance issues.
I've found more than one thread like this: [rubyracer vs nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14829275/3001256).
Are you aware to those issues? Were there any changes in some of the new versions of this gem?

Comment: I have bad experience with `nodejs` on my production Debian Linux server. It has to be installed in a very special way and we've decided to rely on `therubyracer` gem. I don't think there are performance issues, since it is a V8 js machine warper, nothing more or less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, finally, I was able to solve this :)

As it turns out, no was nothing wrong with node.js installation, but with the reference to it.

I have no idea why this was changed in the first place, but [following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24020042/3001256) solved the problem- i.e. by adding the symlink     `ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node`.

Note: I'm pretty sure that the symlink isn't the best practice. If there's anyone who can suggest another idea- I'd love to hear it..

Hopefully this was the last error I'll get with node.js. 
If another errors such as this will occur, therubyracer will provide an excellent backup solution.

Comment: Could someone comment why we even need JS env on production when we can use a web server to serve stuff precompiled in the first place, let alone a rake task that likely doesn't even need anything JS.